# Listing all collections in a mongo database within a nodejs script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I have found a few answers for listing collections in the shell but all the answers I have found for listing collections in a nodejs script seem to have been deprecated, answers like `collectionNames` and `moongose.connection.db` return has no method.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In the 2.0 version of the MongoDB driver for node.js you can use [`listCollections`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections) to get a cursor that contains the information of all collections.  You can then call [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/CommandCursor.html#toArray) on the cursor to retrieve the info.

```
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collInfos) {
    // collInfos is an array of collection info objects that look like:
    // { name: 'test', options: {} }
});
```

Comment: you are a life saver so much deprecated info out there, Didn't you expertly answer one of my previous questions also? would give you plus 5 if I could.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a full example on how you do it with the 3.4 version of the Mongo driver for node

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

// Connection url
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }); // { useUnifiedTopology: true } removes connection warnings;

const dbName = "test";

client
      .connect()
      .then(
        client =>
          client
            .db(dbName)
            .listCollections()
            .toArray() // Returns a promise that will resolve to the list of the collections
      )
      .then(cols => console.log("Collections", cols))
      .finally(() => client.close());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to `async/await`, it is much cleaner to promisify `toArray` on the iterator and not use a callback.

```js
static toArray(iterator) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    iterator.toArray((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```js
const myArray = await toArray(db.listCollections());
```

Comment: in the line of the `toArray` definition, I get `Expected ";" but found "toArray"

Answer (score 1):

```
const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);
```

this gives you a JSON document of your collections.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var resource=[]; 
   var ob=db.getSiblingDB('working_db');
   ob.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(doc){
        var regex = /^word|word1|word2|word3/i;
        var found = doc.match(regex);
        if(found){
            printjson(doc)
            resource.push({ resource: { db: "working_db", collection: doc }, actions: [ "insert","find","remove","update"] })
        }
    });
```

regex used to fetch particular specific words in collection prefix name that we need to be listed, if you do not required, then remove it.
This is very usefull for granting collection specific permission froma huge list of collections.

```
use admin,
db.createRole(
    {
      role: "ROLE_NAME",
      privileges: resource,
      roles: [
        {
          role: "clusterMonitor",
          db: "admin"
        }
      ]
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all collections from a particular database in mongoDB using nodejs

1. first you need to connect to that specific database
2. get a list containing the info of every collection in that database

```
const myDb = mongoose.connection.useDb(<databaseName>);
let collList = await myDb.db.listCollections().toArray();

collList = collList.map(el => {
      return el.name;
    });
```