# How can I get all mongoDB collection names using Node.js code?

Tags: node.js

I want to store all collection names of MongoDB in a variable/array. How can I write nodeJS code to do that?

Comment: You are expected to have some attempt at a solution included in your question, for people to see what your understanding of the problem is and to give them a starting point for a solution. Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all collections in a mongo database within a nodejs script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470415/listing-all-collections-in-a-mongo-database-within-a-nodejs-script)

Answer (score 4):

1. create a connection by providing connection url.
2. create a client to db using database name `client.db(dbName);`
3. call `listCollections` method to get detail info of each collection.
4. finally filter and push the required information and close the connection.

   ```
   const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   mongo.connect(connectionUrl, function(err, client) {
   let allCollections = [];
   //create client by providing database name
   const db = client.db(dbName);
   db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
       if(err) console.log(err);
       //iterate to each collection detail and push just name in array
       collections.forEach(eachCollectionDetails => {
           allCollections.push(eachCollectionDetails.name);
       });
       //close client
       client.close();
    });
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
await db.listCollections().toArray().map(c => c.name);
```

This returns a string array containing the name of every collection.