# How to return this when finish? async question

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

How do I return result" when collection.each is finish? I tried using map but collection isn't an array.

```
function(arg) {
    var result = [];
    db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
    collections = db.listCollections();

    collections.each(function(n, collection) {
        if (collection) {
            result.push(collection.name)
        }
    });
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: I read those, couldn't comprehend how to use promise in this scenario or use async/await.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a promise not the async/await. A callback would do.

Comment: The duplicate has 101 answers. If you can't comprehend any of them then there isn't much we can really add.

Comment: The result is return to the nested function ? Just taking it out the foreach loop ?
```
function(arg) {
    var result = [];
    db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
    collections = db.listCollections();

    collections.each(function(n, collection) {
        if (collection) {
            result.push(collection.name)
        }
    });
  return result;
}

```

Comment: I am actually generating a function using Meteor.methods({
  [updateText.name]: function (args) {
    updateText.validate.call(this, args);
    updateText.run.call(this, args);
  }).  then use call with     Meteor.call('method1', aaa, function (error, result) {   
             console.log(result);
    });
  How would I generate a callback in this scenario.

Comment: @bLaXjack 
i edit the code. i tried that. result would be undefined.

Comment: @MagRon i think this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470415/listing-all-collections-in-a-mongo-database-within-a-nodejs-script