# How to show All Collection Data From MongoDB into nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**Hi,**
is there any way to show all my mongoDB collection content in nodeJS Project.

Comment: Did you do any research? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30470415/3001761 came up when I searched this.

Comment: You've tons of websites explaining this, You need to first do basic research !! Please do not ask for basic things, Post only things where you've issues & not able to find an answer, Check this :: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/tutorials/crud/

Answer (score 2):

To select data from a table in MongoDB, U can use the **find()** method.
*for example*

Find all documents in the customers collection:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.collection("customers").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank your for your response, i really espreciate it ;D