# How to delete the data across the collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's say, I have collections like

```
let employee = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  department: String,
  doj: Date,
  address: String
});

let student= mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  department: String,
  doj: Date,
  address: String
});
let manager= mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  department: String,
  doj: Date,
  address: String
});
```

in my database. I need to delete every data which has department "Computer Science" in each collection(employee, student, manager). I don't know how to do it. I tried deleting data by getting collection names from my database first then querying to remove each data as I said, but it doesn't work as I expected, always return error"db.getCollectionName  is not a function". Any idea how to remove data across the multiple collections at the same time?. I am using node js,express and MongoDB.

Comment: `getCollectName` seems like an odd choice there, are you trying to [list all collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470415/listing-all-collections-in-a-mongo-database-within-a-nodejs-script), or get a single collection with [db.collection](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete matching records for all collections, you can loop through all the models you have registered with Mongoose.

```
 Object.keys(connection.models).forEach(async(collection) => {
        const usersss = mongoose.model(collection)
        await usersss.deleteMany({ defaultAccountId: userParam.defaultAccountId, grnNo: userParam.grnNo })
    })
```