# Connect to existing MongoDB with a new node express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an existing node/express server using mongoose to connect to MongoDB. Everything is working fine.

I'd like to create a separate node/express server to run cron jobs (sending emails, push notifications, etc.)

First of all, would this be a good implementation? (I've looked over message queues like RabbitMQ but seems a bit overkill for what I need.)

Second, I am having difficulty getting my second node/express app connected to the existing MongoDB. I've tried connecting with mongoose and also directly with mongodb and I haven't had much luck.

Here's an example of one of the many things I've tried:

```
const client = new MongoClient(keys.mongoURI, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server
    const db = await client.connect();
    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("my-db").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const users = await db.users.find()
    await console.log(users)

  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

I get `find is not a function`

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database? You are able to connect, so the connections seem not to be a problem, in that case, [check the collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470415/listing-all-collections-in-a-mongo-database-within-a-nodejs-script) available to check if `user` is really present on the database you are connecting to.

Comment: you're running 2 different operations, `data =  await db("dbHere").users.find().toArray(); console.log(data)`

Comment: @luckongas getting warmer! I can see the collections via your suggestion. But how do I get a reference to a collection? I tried swapping `.listCollections()` with `.find()` and that did not work.

@Minsky thank you for your help. That did not work, i got "db is not a function"

Comment: Are you using mongodb driver or mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MongoDB driver this should work:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(keys.mongoURI, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server
    const db = await client.connect();
    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("my-db").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const users = await db("my-db").collection("users").find();
    console.log(users);

  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

While for mongoose, this approach should work:

```js
// You have your mongoose connection to the database and then
async function run() {
  try {
    ... you connect to your database and ping it ...

    const users = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("users").find();
    console.log(users);

  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Please, let me know if you found any other issue